# Run custom script before generating static HTML using Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

I'm using Pelican to generate a static website. I want to run a custom Python script during the build process before the website content is generated in the `output` folder. This script is primarily to do some text replacement via regex parsing. Can someone educate me how this can be achieved (if at all)?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to accomplish the exact same thing you're needing. I needed to update URLs on some `<img>` tags before pushing to Gitlab pages. The only thing I could find was to just add a command to whatever deployment option you're using (Fabric, make, etc.). For example, I'm using `make` to "deploy" my site (output the code to a separate directory/repo which then gets pushed to Gitlab). So in `Makefile`, I appended to the `publish` line like this:

```
publish:
        $(PELICAN) $(INPUTDIR) -o $(OUTPUTDIR) -s $(PUBLISHCONF) $(PELICANOPTS) && find $(OUTPUTDIR)/* -type f -name '*.html' -exec sed -i '' 's/stuff to replace/replacement text/g' {} +
```

I'm pretty ignorant of how to use make, so there's probably a better way to format that in `Makefile`, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task best suited for a Pelican plugin. The first thing I would do is look at the [Pelican Plugin Repository](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins) and see if there is an existing plugin that can deliver the functionality you want. If not, you might consider finding a plugin that is close enough and modifying it to achieve your desired result. The [documentation for Pelican plugins](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/plugins.html#how-to-create-plugins) is reasonably extensive, and if you run into trouble, you can most likely solicit assistance from the folks in the [Pelican IRC channel](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/contribute.html#the-pelican-irc-channel),